# Best method of importing scss variables with React Styled-Components?

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

In normal React components if you have scss, you can import other scss files into them and gain access to scss variables like `$color-primary: blue`...

What's the best method of doing that with styled-components?

Lets say I have some main variables for the app I want to use: font-size, font-family, colors, etc. And I want to be able to import those into a React Component and use them in the styled components of that file?

I know you can set variables in each individual file and use them, but that defeats the purpose of having "global variables" and using them.

**Technically I know styled-components aren't scss, so you probably can't even import a scss file and use the variables from it - so how do you have global variables that all styled-components files can import and use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to have is a tokens file, tokens are used to organize "variable" that describe a property in your design system, https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/#site-main-content.

Luckily for you, this can be accomplished pretty simple in the javascript world. pretty much you only have to create a file where you declare all these constants and then export it and consume it where you want to do it:

I can offer you a simple solution:

```
// tokens.js

const tokens = {
  colorGray1: "#FF1100",
  colorGray2: "#CCC",
  colorGray3: "#DDD",
  colorGray4: "#EEE",
  colorBackgroundBlack: "#000",
}

export default tokens;

// app.js
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-component";
import tokens from "./tokens.js" // this is somewhere in your app

const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  color: ${tokens.colorGray1},
  background: ${tokens.colorBackgroundBlack}
`

export default function MyComponent() {
  return <StyledComponent>This has grey color and black background</StyledComponent>
}
```

also, styled-component has a really good library named polish that emulates mixing and function that sass normally provides https://polished.js.org/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To answer: "how do you have global variables that all styled-components files can import and use?"

You should setup a [Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502813/using-javascript-variables-with-styled-components/45685202#45685202) that can be shared throughout your application via a `ThemeProvider`.

After that perhaps there's some magic where you can import your existing scss variables into the file where your `theme` is initiated and assign those existing vars as needed.... but TBH, I'd just stick to using a `theme` and kill scss (styled-component FTW)

Comment: Didn't deserve the down-vote, IMO the OP presented an X-Y problem and this is a good answer to the actual underlying problem. In fact the question includes: "how do you have global variables that all styled-components files can import and use".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few webpack loaders that will load a scss file and convert the scss variables to a js object. I've used [sass-values-loader](https://github.com/jerryjappinen/sass-values-loader)

```
import styles from './style.scss';
import vars from '!!sass-vars-to-js-loader!./style.scss';

console.log(vars.colorPrimary);
```